# Chrome messaging broken in Chrome Version 57.0.2987?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

We have two Chrome Applications in production, and both have started exhibiting errors this month.

The methods `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.oneMessage.addListener` have stopped working. The listener method just isn't firing.

I've written a toy Chrome OS application to demonstrate this problem...

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("window.onload method called");

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request) {
            console.log('listener method fired');
            let outputElement = document.getElementById("outputTarget");
            outputElement.innerHTML = "A message has been received";
        }
    );

    let button = document.getElementById("btnSendMessage");
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("Button click event fired");
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, "Hello");
    });
};
```

When I run the application and press the button, the following log messages are output to the console:

> window.onload method called
>
> Button click event fired

I do not see the expected console message "listener method fired".

Is there something wrong with this tiny application, or is there indeed a new bug introduced in Chrome OS?